# Error "Waiting for a runner to pick up this job" using GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

When I use GitHub Actions with my config, there is a long waiting and it shows "Waiting for a runner to pick up this job".

What does 'runner' mean? And how can I resolve the problem?

Comment: I tried canceling and re-running the job and it worked.

Answer (score 78):

One potential reason might be that GitHub does not support anymore the operating system you're requesting.

For example, the following would not work:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
```

because GitHub stopped supporting Ubuntu 18.04 on April 1, 2023, see:

https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6002

The solution is to use a supported operating system, for example:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

For a list of supported operating systems, see:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with runs-on: ubuntu-latest

Comment: @JugalAnchalia In this case the problem is most likely different. Sometimes, the actions aren't running because GitHub Actions is down, but it seems ok at the moment: https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: Thanks! I change from `ubuntu-18.04` to `ubuntu-latest` and now works!

Comment: On my case was a error into value `runs-on: ubuntu-lateste` changed to `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`

Comment: lol.. exactly matches my problem.  I want to run on 18.04 for the compatibility though.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti If you need Ubuntu 18.04, you can use a Docker container. I had the same need, so I created a [minimal project](https://github.com/dalboris/test-cpp-github-actions/blob/master/.github/workflows/ubuntu-18.04-docker-minimal.yml) explaining how to do it. I also have a [more complete example](https://github.com/dalboris/test-cpp-github-actions/blob/master/.github/workflows/ubuntu-18.04-docker.yml), as well as an example on how to create a custom Docker image [here](https://github.com/dalboris/ubuntu-18.04-test-cpp-github-actions).

Comment: wow.. I'll try to take a peek at this later today or on the weekend armed with cgpt 4 to help me.  Yes.. I make AppImages that I extract, zip and ship due to fuse confusion issues that can crash ubuntu.  It it called Tipitaka Pali reader.  Currently, I make DO droplet build and destroy.  This will be good for me.   I appreciate your help.. And changing to "latest" did solve the problem to at least see how actions work.

Comment: I could not figure it out.  Seems like you need to create a docker and then do this.. too complex for me.  My solution was to use DigitalOcean, but they recently stopped supporting 18.04.. and hence.. so did I.  Now life is easier.  The one person I know still on 18.04 (that I support) will join the rest of the world soon.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti There is no need to "create a docker". In theory, all you need to do is to replace `runs-on: ubuntu-18.04` by `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` and `container: ubuntu:18.04`. The string `ubuntu:18.04` refers to an already existing Docker image on Docker Hub. However, note that this image is very minimalist so in practice you need to add more install steps than you would on the now-retired GitHub Ubuntu 18.04 image. Example for a C++/Qt project: https://github.com/dalboris/test-cpp-github-actions/blob/master/.github/workflows/ubuntu-18.04-docker.yml

Answer (score 28):

If you misspell the requested runner's name after `runs-on:`, GitHub Actions won't explicitly tell you that you made a mistake. Instead, it will assume that a runner by that name exists and will continue waiting forever for it to be made available.

This is the most common reason why we face this error. Make sure you spell the operating system and architecture name correctly after `runs-on:`.

Comment: This was my problem. It would be super nice if Github did some sort of validation on the `runs-on:` value. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why, in my case it was `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` but got stuck.
This is a free repo so it was strange.

After 3hrs I've cancelled the job and when I've re-ran it got a runner immediately. So it might also be something on GitHub's end.

Comment: Mine hung for 10 minutes and then I tried your fix and it ran correctly.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was petty mistake.

The runs-on was supposed to be **ubuntu-latest**, but was self-hosted. And it was waiting on it for ever.

```yaml
jobs:
  Example-Actions-Job:
    name: Exploring GitHub Actions
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
```

Answer (score 6):

This issue will also happen if you have not shared your self hosted runners with the repo correctly. The `runs-on` line is correct (i.e. there are other jobs with identical `runs-on` elsewhere that are working).

We have GitHub Enterprise runners and the team had correctly added them at the org level but had not authorised the specific repository to use them. It is obvious when you know because the runners tab for the repository is empty but confusing to the team because they did add the runners.

The solution is to go to the org, select the runner or runner group, click on the name, then select the repo from the list of available repos. You may also need to allow public repos or change the visibility of their repo as that also prevents runners being available to a specific repo.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason this might happen is a wrong runner name under:

```
jobs:
  push:
    runs-on: [runner name]
```

Make sure it doesn't contain any typo, I was bashing my head for a few hours because of this the other day

Answer (score 1):

I had a typo in my `.yml` file. I fixed it to
`runs-on: ubuntu-latest`
and now the runner is picking up the job.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and it's like the runner was offline so you need to also check the runner status. I deleted the project folder from VPS so it's showing offline. so I will start again and then working fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused for me because of this:

```yaml
jobs:
  jobA:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: abc
    # ...

  # jobB hangs for ever and wont get started
  jobB:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: xyz
    needs: publish
    # ...
```

The solution was easy: I just removed the `environment`s.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me once I added
`- uses: actions/checkout@v3` to steps property